# How to include CMS block in template file(.phtml)?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to include CMS block in template file(.phtml)

Comment: A simple query on google will give you enormous amount of info.  Please do search on google instead of asking here directly.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to call cms block in phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block-id-here')->toHtml()?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you created the cms static block like "my_block_id", Use the below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this question answered many times in this forum, I dont know why you ask same question again,

but you can try below things.

if your template(PHTML)'s block class extends `mage_core_block_template` at some where then you can easily use below code

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Your_CMS_Block_Identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

IF your Templeate's block class does not extends `mage_core_block_template` at some point then you can try below code in your `phtml` file

```
 <?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Your_CMS_Block_Identifier')->toHtml(); ?
```

Comment: Is there any way to fetch the cms block using the "ID" not the identifier ?

Comment: @AnishKarim try this `<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setId('Your_CMS_Block_Id')->toHtml(); ? `

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block.name">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_block_id_</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
<your_layout_handle>
```

In your phtml you put this where you want to display it:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('block.name') ?>
```